# how to swap current fragment shader color with neighbors?

Tags: colors, three.js, shader, swap

I have a shader with a sampler texture. is it possible to swap the color of the current fragment with any of its neighbors? if it so, how?

```
 uniform sampler2D map;

 varying vec2 vuv;

void main() {

   gl_FragColor = texture2D(map, vuv);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fragment shader only knows about current fragment. The only way to swap colors would be to create pass where everything is rendered to texture and then one post-processing pass to swap colors. Hope this helps.